# mockito, wanted but not invoked

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have a problem.
I create object  with mockito. Then I do the verification of the method and when running the test, it gives me error of Wanted but not invoked. And that the service stays as ().

```
@Test
    public void recordTest() throws IOException, URISyntaxException
    {

    URL resourceUrl = getClass().getResource(F1);
    Path resourcePath = Paths.get(resourceUrl.toURI());

    Object object = new Object ();
    when(objectServiceMock.getObjectByNem((Nem) anyObject())).thenReturn(object);

    Page<HorvarATPF> pageHorvar = new Page<HorvarATPF>();
    when(horvarATPFServiceMock.getHorvarATPFs((FilterHorvarATPF) anyObject())).thenReturn(pageHorvar);

    horvarATUtilService.record(resourcePath.toFile());

    verify(objectServiceMock, times(1596)).getObjectByNem((Nem) anyObject());

}
```

test doesn´t run in line of verify, with Wanted buy not invoked.

Comment: Are you sure your method is invoked *exactly* 1596 times?

Comment: yes, i changed this sometimes and the problem continued.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proble is

```
verify(objectServiceMock, times(1596)).getObjectByNem((Nem) anyObject())
```

Mockito expects  that you call this method 1596 times.

But you declare that it calls just once.

```
when(objectServiceMock.getObjectByNem((Nem) anyObject()).
```

To fix test just put

```
verify(objectServiceMock).getObjectByNem((Nem) anyObject());
```

or

```
verify(objectServiceMock, times(1)).getObjectByNem((Nem) anyObject())
```

here is examples from mockito documentation [Verifying exact number of invocations / at least x / never](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.8.9/org/mockito/Mockito.html#4)